# XAMPP when configured to port 8080 and hosts file (and WordPress-mu install) issue

Tags: xampp

I am trying to install [WordPress MU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress#Multi-blogging) in my [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) localhost server (that is configured to port 8080).

Using this address in the browser >>http://localhost:8080/wordpress-mu/<<
gets this response >>WPMU only works without the port number in the URL.<<

This is the last line in my hosts file:
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain

(This points to my IIS7 localhost server not to my XAMPP local host)

I am guessing I need to add another entry in this hosts file to configure this for XAMPP and WordPress MU but am not sure what it should be?

Comment: Thank you soooo much! My headaches are over as my XAMPP only wanted to work on 8080. It can now find and run wordpress setup. I had to create my own wp-config file according to their instructions but this worked. Also had to use localhost instead of localhost8080 which is what XAMPP keeps calling it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using IIS at all?

If not, just **Stop the Server** and point your XAMPP to port 80.

If you are, you can do the **reverse**, just open Default Website properties and in the *Website Bindings* just change 80 to 8080.

In your **XAMPP** instalation change the port to 80:

- Open C:\XAMPP\APACHE\httpd.conf
- Search for Listen (default instalation, on line 47)
- Change the port
- Restart Apache

Comment: Hi balexandre
Thanks for your reply. I do want to use IIS7 and Xampp together on my computer so just changing one or the other to use port 80 isn't the solution for me I'm afraid. Surely I can have IIS7 on default port80 & Xampp on port8080 and install WordPress-mu on Xampp localhost.localdomain?

Comment: Why dont you install Wordpress in IIS ?

Comment: Hi there-good you mention that, as I am right now trying to install WordPressMU in IIS7. If / when I get it done I will post an update here...thanks

Comment: use Web Platform Installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to install Wordpress and then Wordpress MU will be sweet :) (Remember Wordpress 3.0 will have MU already builted in) ;)

Comment: OK- I have installed Wordpress on IIS7 using the WebPlatform Installer (Thanks for the link).Now how do I make a sweet install for WordPressMU?

Comment: After I enter details at WordPressMU install page and click install it goes to the next page which is blank-apart from WordPress MU header-! (should be the completed install page). There must be something wrong with the details I enter (possibly the Database?)-anyone suggest help please?

Comment: I managed to restore an old install of wordpress-mu but trying to import data I get this error message:
Unable to create directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress-mu/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2010/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Perhaps this is not the right place to ask but anyone  any idea how I fix this?

Comment: Well I added the folders to wp-content folder & it allowed me to import data but then did not complete & gave this message:
Sorry, there has been an error.
The uploaded file could not be moved to the upload folder.

This is all presumambly because this is part of a broken repair-oh well-perhaps I have to wait for wordpress3!

Comment: I think you should start an answer under http://serverfault.com/ about "How to install WP MU under IIS" and tell everything and why are you installing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make apache from xampp use port 80 (wich is the default port for http).
* Edit httpd.conf and change the line `Listen 8080` to `Listen 80`
* Make sure there is no other service listening on port 80
* Restart Apache
* Browse to `http://localhost/wordpress-mu/`

If you cannot for some reason use port 80 for apache try with mod_rewrite
* make sure that the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in httpd.conf exsists and is not commented
* in your htdocs folder make a .htaccess file and write in it the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^:8080/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi clyfe
Thanks for your reply. I do not want to change Xampp port to default 80 as my IIS7 localhost uses port 80.
I tried your second suggestion but only achieved this error message after typing this address http://localhost/wordpress-mu/

>>Warning!
Installing to http://localhost/ is not supported. Please use http://localhost.localdomain/ instead
<<

Anything else I can try?

Comment: try and use http://127.0.0.1 or add in your hosts file the line `127.0.0.1 localhosts`

Comment: how would you do the reverse with the port rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

OK this reply is to update this with my fix (problem resolved).
I did change the ports-so I put Xampp back to its default port 80 & changed IIS7 from its default port80 to port 8080. This allows me now to install & run WPMU in Xampp (it does not run in IIS7-still an issue with the address & I don't really fully understand why I cannot run WPMU in IIS7 but at least I can run it through Xampp now).
Thanks for all your help-best wishes to all