# i tried to connect 192.168.1.20/ localhost/ 10.0.2.2 but not not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, networking, retrofit

i tried to connect to retrofit in Ubuntu. it execute the failure method. i tried port 8080 and 3000 also. i don't know where is problem occur. it perfectly working on server url.

emulator show error is ***cannot connect to 10.0.2.2:3000***

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brg_dsk005.pikaainstruction">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

function: fetching function from retrofit

```
private void TaketestReq() {

       /* private JsonObject ApiJsonMap() {
            JsonObject gsonObject = new JsonObject();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj_ = new JSONObject();
                jsonObj_.put("key", "value");
                jsonObj_.put("key", "value");
                jsonObj_.put("key", "value");
                JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                gsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObj_.toString());
                //print parameter Log.e("MY gson.JSON: ", "AS PARAMETER " + gsonObject); }
                // catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } return gsonObject; }
*/

        JsonObject gsonObject = new JsonObject();


        JsonObject paramObject = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject current_section = new JsonObject();

        paramObject.addProperty("test_id", 5);
        paramObject.addProperty("user_id", "null");
        paramObject.addProperty("org_id", 2);
        paramObject.addProperty("schedule_id", 15);
        paramObject.addProperty("next_section_id","");
        paramObject.addProperty("group_id", "null");


        paramObject.addProperty("current_section", String.valueOf(current_section));
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        gsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(paramObject.toString());
        Log.e("MY gson.JSON: ", "AS PARAMETER " + gsonObject);

        Call<Test_Responce> userCall = api_interface.testRes(gsonObject);
        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Test_Responce>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Test_Responce> call, Response<Test_Responce> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getUserName().toLowerCase(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"else",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Test_Responce> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

retrofit connection :here i attached retrofit service code

```
public class RetrofitServiceGenrator {
    //private static final String EndPoint = "http://pikatestengine.brigita.co/testengine/public/api/";
    private static final String EndPoint = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/testengine/public/api/";

    private static Api_interface retrofitClient = null;

    public static Api_interface getRetrofitClient(Context context){

        if (retrofitClient == null){

            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjAyODkyMzI5NzdjNjczZTlmZDExYmVkOGYzNTBiYTY2YjhmMjNjNWVkYjU4ZDM5NmMxM2I3YjJhYjZhOWVkYmMwZTlkZWI0MDhiYmI3MjAzIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIzIiwianRpIjoiMDI4OTIzMjk3N2M2NzNlOWZkMTFiZWQ4ZjM1MGJhNjZiOGYyM2M1ZWRiNThkMzk2YzEzYjdiMmFiNmE5ZWRiYzBlOWRlYjQwOGJiYjcyMDMiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzEyMTk3NjksIm5iZiI6MTUzMTIxOTc2OSwiZXhwIjoxNTYyNzU1NzY5LCJzdWIiOiIyNCIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.dA6OvGg4rwU13bzVITzOcJpdhUJico1YwaJpAwvcxISghk7yVqEhJunDByAOR1nk5bScwUv5RUERRIbXd1QPk5mxkbmZdZNPGRh__QswWLLaorGB0gma7NwmS42V3zKH0e-n9T6ZJivZP2PgmuTwnTouFv3dE3uf-jc0dK9dYZMw9ClzEY-U7_W75bwUDKOROxFfQf0yIuOR4zPMD0LePgWYheKRI1soYoEfT1hfAjUEMFpjGRlyQy_aVRXYVQJunLyeuaHEYzGhXeNu_Yy1-tiBUqaHDSH6zIYfYXUKtD4-RH33iZcOIEuIh9QPzgf-v-WEPorlroMed9HlLv-ctmcptj9p4kIW8g5jZ6NEuReOKGcjiTFqrikPhiYw7SEhU_Q_lo0gUentJSO_VjQUPsOO0WVAKOGRpgnuDIjs3H2MZTTiae_6cbcLJUGc8_irSTY9i_4AewBQ2e3EQMFdUVf8fFYvYVP3OEA-Ys1bNZiGQCckhLbLroQDgDF6NbnVpUdqvWMMnKignXAtxKAiNcsdRHbfw6DH-Trg5syd0152yXVGxqCx9SpW7d0ypOh98lwwDGr10B7BduRLzkJDrTREP6TwHf34lJ4FAN1LdDvUAjwoaP-d8gmJw6sAl15_in25G6emcMbwXeW0EC-sMY0A6qP5NzKYgYeBsLk8Z9k")
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }

            });
            OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(EndPoint)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client).build();

            retrofitClient = retrofit.create(Api_interface.class);
        }

        return retrofitClient;
    }

}
```

interface:

```
  @POST("take_tests")
    Call<Test_Responce> testRes (@Body JsonObject paramObject);
```

Comment: please share the retrofit code also

Comment: now i shared retrofit code also

Comment: is your emulator is `Google Android Virtual Devices` or `Genymotion Android Virtual Devices` ?

Comment: Which local server you are using for your apis and why you are trying 8080 and 3000, it seems like just hit and try.
you should know the port number on which your local server is running and the ip too if you are connected to a network. so the format could be `http://ipaddress:port/testengine/public/api/`

Comment: i tried without port also. i am using xampp. it not working

Comment: my emulator is google android virtual device

Comment: how can you skip the port number, do you know the port no of xampp.
Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/2378709/5901903 for port number

Comment: i checked. i tried 80,8080,3000 ports. my xampp port is 80

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is your local ip?
print the url in log and share,
can you post your error log

Comment: could you check your ip using ipconfig/ifconfig in terminal/command prompt?

Comment: ok , i will check

Comment: @ParamasivamMathesh first check your local ip address.. then check the folder of xampp in which your file is.. may be it is in htdocs.. so check that correct path.. then make a url like : `http://your.ip.address/your/path/for/xampp/php/file/name`.. if without port you can run in bt=rowser then no need to write port

Answer (score 0):

Might be possibe, it cant access the localhost network, please add below permission in android manifest and try

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code useful to you,
try this.

```
10.0.2.2 is your local ip? print the url in log and share, can you post your error log
```