# Local wordpress installation issues on port 8080

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I'm using XAMPP as my local apache server. For some reason I can't use Port 80 and hence I changed the Listen and Servername to localhost:8080.
Now when I'm trying to install a wordpress site I'm getting the below error if I put localhost:3306 or localhost
[wp-installation-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKcsh.jpg)

And If I try to specify localhost:8080 as DB host, it goes into a "waiting for localhost" and times out after few minutes.
[setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTibX.jpg)

Can someone help me how to set it up?

Comment: As you have XAMPP you should also have phpMyAdmin, try to open it and see what is its location. I thing from there you can guess if your database will be accessible from 8080. Also found  [this](http://marvintam.com/2009/05/wordpress-on-localhost-port-number/) article that might be related to your case.

Comment: Hi @ale: thanks for your reply. Yes I've tried to open phpadmin. its opening at "http://localhost:8080/phpadmin". Can you suggest what should i use for the DB connection?

Comment: not much of idea what might be then. Localhost:8080 should work for connection with the database, but this time out is no good. You can check your logs files for some clues and errors. It might be that something else is also on port 8080. If there is nothing useful in the error log then I would suggest to create a new XAMPP server and move your files there. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378515/xampp-when-configured-to-port-8080-and-hosts-file-and-wordpress-mu-install-iss?rq=1) is some issue with setting wp to work with locahost:8080